# I am sending form data which includes files as well, however while accessing req.files in express it returning undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, undefined

I am sending formdata in my react app which includes file also. However when I try to access req.files in my express server it always return "Undefined". (I have gone through similar questions but they are not resolving my problem)
Here is my Client side code

```
const AddCategory = () => {
    const categoryName = useRef("");
    const categoryImage = useRef("");

    async function PostCategory(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //checking file type and size
        categoryImage.current.files[0].type.slice(0, 5) != "image" ? alert("Only Images are acceptable") :
            categoryImage.current.files[0].size > 1024 * 1024 ? alert("Oversized Image File") : 
                console.log("Continue");
        
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', JSON.stringify(categoryName.current.value));
        data.append('file', categoryImage.current.files[0]);

        let response = await fetch("AddCategory", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        })

    }
    return (
        <div>
            <NavigationBar />
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <h3>Add Category</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={(e) => PostCategory(e)} id="AddCategory" className="text-alignment-left">
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Group as={Col} className="mb-3" controlId="formGridcategoryName">
                            <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control ref={categoryName} type="text" required />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                            <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control ref={categoryImage} name="categoryImage" type="file" accept="image/*" required />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
                        Add Category
                    </Button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my server side code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routesHandler = require('./routes/handlers.js');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', routesHandler);
app.use(fileUpload())

const PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(PORT);
})

router.post("/AddCategory", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Request Received");
    console.log(req.files.file);
      });
```

May anybody suggest what is going wrong?